# what is wrong with this script? the function does not replace the old email with a new one

Tags: python

I tried to write a script that replaces Hotmail address with Gmail if found in the input, but there is something wrong with the function I think. There is no syntax error but the result just does not output the replaced Gmail domain but the same Hotmail one.

```
old_email = "hotmail.com"
new_email = "gmail.com"
email = input("Enter email: ")

def replace_domain(email, old_email, new_email):
    if "@" + old_email in email.endswith:
        index = len(old_email)
        new = email[:-index]+ "@" + new_email
        return new
    return email
a = email
print(a)
```

Comment: You never call the function.

Comment: `email.endswith` is a function. You need to call it, and the argument has to be a string with the ending you want to test.

Comment: You could use a regular expression: `return re.sub(r'@hotmail\.com$', '@gmail.com', email)`

Answer (score 5):

Here's the fixed code and then I'll explain what I've changed:

```py
old_email = "hotmail.com"
new_email = "gmail.com"
email = input("Enter email: ")

def replace_domain(email, old_email, new_email):
    if email.endswith("@" + old_email):
        index = len(old_email)
        new = email[:-index] + new_email
        return new
    return email

a = replace_domain(email, old_email, new_email)
print(a)
```

**First**: There was no call to the function. I've added that to the penultimate line.

**Second**: `endswith` is a function. I've therefore changed that line so that the function is called with the old email domain.

**Third**: The `@` was being output twice, because it isn't removed in the `:-index` part and then a new one is added immediately afterwards.

I would also make some recommendations:

**Fourth**: `a` is not a descriptive variable name, which makes the code harder to read. Similarly, `index` and `new` are not ideal variable names. Words like `new` are best avoided as variable names, because they can easily clash with built-in names.

**Fifth**: I would consider changing the variable name `old_email` to `old_domain` instead. Same with `new_email`. This is a better match for the contents of that variable.

Example output:

```
Enter email: robson@hotmail.com
robson@gmail.com
```

Another example output:

```
Enter email: robson@aol.com
robson@aol.com
```

Comment: `return email.replace("@"+old_domain, "@"+new_domain)`? Why get index, slice, if, ...? If you want to replace, just replace ...

Comment: @Thomas-Weller That's a much better solution, but I feel that we aren't helping the question asker if we just give a completely different solution, without explaining why their code was problematic. Especially as the question began with "what is wrong with this script?"

Comment: Maybe we need both

Comment: Mission accomplished then!

Comment: That's one of the most beautiful answers I've ever seen in StackOverflow.